# How can I match keywords before punctuation with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the regexp below which match every keyword but "excel" before the punctuation, in this case a dot and a comma.

```
(?<!\S)(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|.net)(?!\S)
```

https://regex101.com/r/K1WT05/1

**Text:**
BIexcel communications excel, nibh excellent communications quis technology- software & framework C# Quisque convallis communication technology-based skills vulputate excel. 
auctor excellent blandit and c++ catoon .net luctus. .net microsoft self-excel.

So the question is, how can I match keywords before punctuation?

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/2aJxXt/1

Comment: Thanks for answering, but we need to keep the current matches in order. In your example, technology-based is half matched, excel appears in self-excel while it shouldn't and also technology appears in technology- with the hyphen.

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/2aJxXt/2, just make sure longeralternatives come before shorter ones.

Comment: Try this `(?<!\S)(excel|technology-based|technology|c#|software & framework|.net)(?!\B\S)`

Comment: `(?<!\S)`  lookbehind assertions are not supported in the firefox I'm using.

Comment: This construct `(?<!\S)` is really this `(?<![^\s])`. So all that's needed is to put the comma and dot in with the whitespace, like this `(?<![^\s,.])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|.net)(?![^\s,.])` as seen here https://regex101.com/r/rKnjP5/1

Comment: Thanks but this is not working in my code for some reasons, see jsfiddle example further down.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the characters `a-z0-9`, including the `-`

```js
let content = `BIexcel communications excel, nibh excellent communications quis technology- software & framework C# Quisque convallis communication technology-based skills vulputate excel. 
auctor excellent blandit and c++ catoon .net luctus. .net microsoft self-excel.`

let matches = content.match(/(?<![\w-])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|\.net)(?![\w-])/gi)

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Thanks, your Regex works in Regex101 but not in my code for some reasons. see: https://jsfiddle.net/seb_london/wm9yqazj/1/ 
the keyword "excel" is still highlighted in "BIexcel" and in "excellent".

Comment: I needed two backslashes before the "w" as mentioned by The fourth bird user.

So instead of this: 

    (?<![\w-])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|.net)(?![\w-])

I needed this: 

    (?<![\\w-])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|.net)(?![\\w-])